# Paragraph leading in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

I know how to set the general leading for at text box in Illustrator.

However, I would like to know if there's a way to set leading between paragraphs?

[image: paragraph leading]

Comment: This is normally referred to as "paragraph spacing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use the Space After option on the Paragraph Panel.

[image]

Comment: Great! Thx for helping me out :)

Comment: There's "space before" as well, to the left of where Scott has ringed. It's much less used, but it can be important in some cases, e.g. headings which have different leading to body text. But that's another question...;-)